# How can i use this font in Pdflatex?

Tags: fonts, ebgaramond

[image]

This font is Garamond written by mathtype. Is there a latex command that gives this. the command `\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}`doesn't give the same font.

Comment: You need to have Garamond installed.  Even if you have a complete working TeX installation, you may still need to add the "non-free" fonts to get all of Garamond.  See http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/

Comment: When you do have it installed what you have above will produce maths in Garamond, but it won't look quite like the "mathtype" output, for example, I don't think TeX uses the swash-y in maths, so your "dy dx" will look a bit more straight-laced.

Comment: @Thruston Since this question seems to have been answered, consider your reply as an answer with maybe a few more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use Garamond with `mathdesign` you must have Garamond installed.  Even if you have a complete working TeX installation you may still need to add the "non-free" fonts to get all of Garamond.  See [the instructions at the TUG site](http://www.tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/).

If you have not got the right font, then `pdflatex` will complain about not being able to read `ugmr8a.pfb`.

When you do have the right fonts installed, then you get Garamond like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}
\begin{document}
\noindent
We can write $\int_a^\infty(x-a)^2\,f(x)\,d\!x=\int_a^\infty\!\int_a^x
2(y-a)f(x)\, d\!y\,d\!x$.
\end{document}
```

Note that it won't look quite like the output produced by your "Mathtype" package.  For example, as you can see TeX does not use the swash-form "y" in math mode, and the "x" character is slightly more respectable.

[image]

Notice that I manually added some negative space with `\!` and some positive space with `\,` in order to make "dy dx" look right in this font.