# Installing EB Garamond for pdfLaTeX (encore)

Tags: fonts, pdftex, miktex, installing

At the moment I try to get the EB Garamond font to work on my windows machine (under MikTeX 2.9), but I failed. By searching TeX.SX I found this two questions:

- [EB Garamond on LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60098/eb-garamond-on-latex)
- [Installing EBGaramond for pdfLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138718/installing-ebgaramond-for-pdflatex)

The first solution is too generic because it only points out the existence of the `ebgaramond` package on CTAN, while the second one consists in reinstalling the package by hand - which I tried without success.

As the [README](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/fonts/ebgaramond/README) of `ebgaramond` demands I enabled the font-map of EB Garamond (by adding

```
Map EBGaramond.map
```

to the `updmap.cfg`, and then Refreshing FNDB and bashing

```
initexmf -u
updmap
```

to the Windows command line.) Is this alredy wrong? Maybe I am missing something completely basal in my test file:

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{ebgaramond}
 %\usepackage[DIV10]{typearea}
 %\usepackage{microtype}
 \usepackage{lipsum}

 \title{A \LaTeX\ Article}
 \author{Ruben Giannotti}
 \date{\today}

 \begin{document}
 \maketitle
 {{\large 1}\hspace{.5em}\scshape \uppercase{Introduction}\par\vspace{1em}}%faking a section title
 \lipsum
 \end{document}
```

When compiling with LaTeX a really bad looking `.dvi` emerges. (So I guess the maping should be alright.) But, when doing so with pdfLaTeX not even an output file is generated. The log file says:

> !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file EBGaramond12-Regular-osf-t1--base): Font EBGaramo
>   nd12-Regular-osf-t1--base at 548 not found
>    ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

By enabling `microtype` it changes a little:

> ! pdfTeX error (font expansion): auto expansion is only possible with scalable 
>   fonts.
>    
>                      \endgroup \set@typeset@protect 
>   l.17 \end
>            {document}
>   ...
>   !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

### Edit

In the meantime I tried several things with the font mapping configuration. What I did in the first place was to modify `updmap.cfg` in the root directory of MikTeX, which is not ideal. So, I restored it to its original state. Afterwords I started the configuration with `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap` (which opens the corresponding config file in the roaming directory of MikTeX - at least on my machine). I finally made EB Garamond to work *but* - and this is a non acceptable drawback - I had to cancel out another mapping that I added before (MinionPro).

In short: With my actual knowledge and setup I can use only one of them, and what I deduce from what I did til now is that I simply use the wrong syntax to map the *fonts* (note the plural form) correctly. This is how my `updmap.cfg` looks like:

```
Map EBGaramond.map Map MinionPro.map Map MyriadPro.map
```

By the way, I did this because the MikTeX manual says

> "Insert the following line at the end of the file: Map xyz.map"

Do I have to respect some syntax rules? Is this even wrong? Or could this be a sign that my whole distro is broken (see @DG's comments on his/her answer)?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146595/how-can-i-use-this-font-in-pdflatex) help?

Comment: @Thruston unfortunately no. Since the question is about math fonts and urw-garamond.

Comment: Is using `LuaLaTeX` instead of `pdfLaTeX` an option for you? The OpenType version of `EB Garamond` has lots of cool features, but they're best accessed via `LuaLaTeX` and the `fontspec` package.

Comment: @Mico in general I'd say: yes. Trying out new stuff is very important (to me). In this specific case I have set up a document that will be handed in soon and while finishing it I had the idea to play around with alternate fonts. As the coding is somehow finished too and I don't know if there could be compatibility problems with LuaLaTeX (because I don't know it yet), I guess it is not really an option for now.

Comment: If you really want to use `EBGaramond`, then do as Mico says. Using the OpenType version with `LuaLaTex` (or `XeLaTeX`) is likely to succeed quite easily, while figuring out what went wrong installing the font for `pdflatex` has wasted a lot of time already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this post [Are itemize and EBGaramond compatible?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135781/are-itemize-and-ebgaramond-compatible) there is a bug in EBGaramond.

Using the code @egreg posted in his answer, you can fix your example like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifluatex,ifxetex}

\ifluatex\else\ifxetex\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi\fi

\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\ifluatex\else\ifxetex\else
  \normalfont
  \makeatletter
  \input{TS1EBGaramond-LF.fd}
  \input{TS1EBGaramond-OsF.fd}
  \makeatother
  \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{m}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/n }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{it}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{b}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{n}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/n }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{it}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{TS1}{EBGaramond-OsF}{bx}{sl}{ <-> ssub * EBGaramond-OsF/m/it }{}
\fi\fi

\usepackage[DIV10]{typearea}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{A \LaTeX\ Article}
\author{Ruben Giannotti}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
 \maketitle
 {{\large 1}\hspace{.5em}\scshape \uppercase{Introduction}\par\vspace{1em}}%faking a section title
 \lipsum
\end{document}
```

---

The package `ebgaramond` [is in the repository of miktex](http://miktex.org/packages/ebgaramond), so it is advisable to use the package manager, instead of installing it manually.

**Update**

If this does not help, follow the steps outlined in the [miktex manual](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/advanced.html#psfonts):

1. Run `initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`.
2. Check for `Map EBGaramond.map` and add it at the end of the file, if absent. Make sure each entry is on its own line.
3. Save the file and close the editor.
4. Run `initexmf --mkmaps` to rebuild the font map files.
5. It couldn't hurt to additionally run `initexmf --update-fndb`

Comment: I tried this code; but still no pdf output.

Comment: Have you installed the `ebgaramond` using the miktex package manager? Either by using the [gui tool](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html) or by invoking `mpm --install ebgaramond` on the command line.

Comment: I cleaned up the previous installation of the package, and then tried both. `pdfLaTeX` still refuses to give at least an output file.

Comment: This is strange, can you post the relevant part of your log?

Comment: It is still the one from the end of the questions body.

Comment: Well, it seems like (pdf)latex can't find the font. Try rebuilding the font map files. Reinstall the package (again). There are user who ended up [reinstalling their whole LaTeX-](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/de.comp.text.tex/ebgaramond/de.comp.text.tex/TPTPRmC1kzg/lwAHp-C23ekJ)...

Comment: I figured out some facts about it. Thanks for the hint. See my edit for a few details. Maybe you know what to do now.

Comment: Maybe it is just a quirk in your formating, but each `Map fontname.map` entry should be on a line of it's own. It couldn't hurt to additionally do  `initexmf --update-fndb`.

Comment: This is crazy. I could have sworn that I alredy tried it... Finally this was the key. Maybe add a little edit to the answer, so that I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Glad the mystery is solved! Still, it should be the job of the package manager to do all this...

Answer (score 3):

Even though the OP has indicated a reluctance to switch from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX so close to the submission deadline, I'll offer the following method anyway, as it's really not that difficult to implement:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{EB Garamond}
% Remainder of document same as before, except: Don't load the
% fontenc, inputenc, or ebgaramond packages
```

Don't load the `fontenc` or `inputenc` packages, but do ensure that your .tex files are encoded in `utf8`. (If it's encoded in ASCII, you'll be fine.)