# Installing MinionPro on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts, installing, ubuntu, minionpro

I am trying to install the 'MinionPro' font to be used with LaTeX on Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded the files and followed instructions from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/). I am having trouble with section 7:

> 7) Add the line
>
> ```
>  Map MinionPro.map
> ```
>
> to your updmap.cfg. Refresh the file database and run updmap:

I appear to have multiple `updmap.cfg` files:

```
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

I have tried adding the appropriate line in each by running:

```
sudo gedit /root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
```

changing the file path each time. When I subsequently run

```
sudo mktexlsr
sudo updmap
```

I get a whole list of errors being returned, including:

> updmap [WARNING]: font MinionPro-MediumItSubh-Base-aa is defined multiple times:
>
> updmap [WARNING]:   MinionPro.map (from /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)
>
> updmap [WARNING]:   MinionPro (from /root/.texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg) (used)
>
> updmap [WARNING]: font MinionPro-MediumItSubh-integral is defined multiple times:
>
> updmap [WARNING]:   MinionPro.map (from /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg)

Any thoughts as to the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In a previous version of the OP you talked about using the font in TeXmaker -- which is "only" an editor for `.tex` manuscripts, hence independant from the actual problem as you need to tell the actual software (LaTeX) on how to handle the font.

Comment: I had a very similar problem once: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146894/installing-eb-garamond-for-pdflatex-encore (its solution and the comments to the OP might help you).

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution in the previous post

Comment: Why don't you use `xelatex` and `fontspec`? Are a few `microtype` functions really worth the trouble?

Comment: I have been using TexMaker for a couple of years to write manuscripts and never had a problem before, so saw no reason to change. Having decided that I had probably broken tex-live and tex-common with all my fiddling I purged all instances from my machine (and TexMaker for some element of totality). I will run `sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex` to install. Can you recommend a link for installing the minion font?

Comment: This is not an issue of problems or editors. It's that installing fonts in LaTeX is unbelievably complicated. With `xelatex` or `lualatex`, there is no need for that. Minion is a paid font, but you can get it installing Acrobat Reader or some of the Adobe programs and install it *on your system* (I had supposed you already had the `.otf` fonts, because you tried to install the package).

Comment: I will give xelatex a try. I found a link on how to specify the .otf fonts (yes, I already have them) Thanks

Comment: I changed TexMaker to XeLaTeX, put the minionpro files in the directory of the document I am interested in and voila! Thanks @Joseph

Comment: @N.Crouch, you can also install those fonts system-wide. If you're on Linux, just make a `.fonts` folder in /home/user, copy the files there, and you're done.